# Icinga2 check_mem plugin doesn't accept parameters

Tags: monitoring, nagios, icinga

​Hello,

I've created a custom command in Icinga 2 using this plugin:

https://github.com/justintime/nagios-plugins/blob/master/check_mem/check_mem.pl​

## check_command

```
object CheckCommand "memory" {
  import "plugin-check-command"
  command = [ PluginDir + "/check_mem" ]

  arguments = {
    "-w" = {
     required = true 
     value = "$mem_warning$"
    }

    "-c" = {
     required = true
     value = "$mem_critical$"
    }
    "-u" = {
     required = true
     value = "$mem_used$"
    }

    "-C" = "$mem_cache$"
  }

  vars.mem_used = true
  vars.mem_cache = true
  vars.mem_warning = 85
  vars.mem_critical = 95
```

}

## service

```
apply Service "Memory" {
  import "generic-service"
  check_command = "memory"
  assign where host.address
}
```

However the plugin cannot check the memory and gives the following output in Icinga Web 2 interface:

## ​Plugin Output

*** You must define WARN and CRITICAL levels!
\ncheck_​mem.​pl v1.​0 - Nagios Plugin\n\nusage:​\n check_​mem.​pl -\ncheck_​mem.​pl comes with absolutely NO WARRANTY either implied or explicit\nThis program is licensed under the terms of the\nMIT License (check source code for details)

Could you please help, what is wrong with this check?

Answer (score 2):

This works with your service

```
object CheckCommand "memory" {
    import "plugin-check-command"
    command = [ PluginDir + "/check_mem.pl" ]

    arguments = {
      "-w" = {
         value = "$mem_warning$" 
      }
     "-c" = {
        value ="$mem_critical$"
      }
     "-u" = {
        set_if = "$mem_used$"
     }
     "-C" = {
        set_if = "$mem_cache$"
     }  
   }

    vars.mem_warning = 85
    vars.mem_critical = 95
    vars.mem_used = true
    vars.mem_cache = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give like this, you command will get values from service at run time.

```
apply Service "Memory" {
  import "generic-service"
  check_command = "memory"
  vars.mem_used = true
  vars.mem_cache = true
  vars.mem_warning = 85
  vars.mem_critical = 95
  assign where host.address
}
```

This will replaced while execution [refering this will help](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/monitoring-basics#command-runtime-macros) .If you are using NRPE, please update your question with that, answer may differ for that please refer [arguments passing icinga to NRPE](https://www.icinga.org/2015/10/28/understanding-commands-in-icinga-2/).